# Python type that matches the date type in Html

Tags: python, html

I have an html page with an input type date form

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <label for="date">Choose a date:</label>
    <input type="date">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And I want to compare the submitted form with a date in python

```
date = request.form.get("date")
if date==var
```

Of which type must var be?

Comment: you will get it as `str` and you should convert it to python `date` (if you need to run date logic)

Comment: @balderman Can you show me the code of how you would do it?

Comment: see https://stackabuse.com/converting-strings-to-datetime-in-python/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All inputs from a HTML form are transmitted as strings. So, to match for example the date `22.08.21`, you would simply do:

```py
date = request.form.get("date")
if date == "2021-08-22":
    print("matched !")
```

Note: I have found out using below snippet that the date get's transmitted in the format `<year>-<month>-<day>`, not in the format I am used to: `<day>.<month>.<year>`. This may be different in a different browser - I am using FireFox.

```html
<input type="date" onchange="console.log(this.value);">
```